# Regular Expression for matching a url with a query string including a dot but not a URL for a static file?

Tags: regex, node.js, url

I'm developing a Single Page App on the web and just found a exception when redirecting to index.html for all request except request to static files.

This is my current config

```
modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'])
```

This matches everything that does not contain a '.' (period) and redirects the request to index.html.

The problem is if I request a URL like this.

```
www.example.com/test?q=include.period
```

It will not redirect this to index.html because it contains a dot in the query string, and it will think this is a static file with the document type *.period*.

I have tried to get a match on URL not containing a dot before any question mark, but can't get it working.
It is hosted on NodeJS.

I'm not very good with regex so any help would be appriciated.

## Examples

**Should match**

- /test
- /test/123
- /test/123/1
- /test/123/1?q=test
- /test/123/1?q=test.period

**Should mot match (file ending can be any type of file)**

- /test.js
- /img/123.jpg
- /script/app.js?version=1.0

Thanks

Comment: can you place some examples for url that will be redirected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
\/[^.\n]*?(?:=.*)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/17)

Comment: It does not quit work, it matches all URLS from my example, see question abow, http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/11

Comment: Why the first and second lines under should not be matches is not to matched? It isn't have any `?` symbol.

Comment: I tried to boild down the question to most essential, and that was the question mark and period matching. It is part of this bigger problem. Sorry for making it unclear.

Comment: @Acinash I'v updated the example URLs again, I'm trying to match all URLs wich is not to a static file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Acinash That works perfectly, the only thing I had to do was to escape  the backslash with 2 backslashes because JS things \n is special! =) Change your answere to regex v17 and I mark as answere! Thanks!